# scanner problem

Tags: upgrade

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.4 to 22.4 LTS and lost the HP Icon and the printer still works OK but trying to use the "Document Scanner" program, nothing works.
When trying to Uninstall the document Scanner program, nothing happens either.
It gives me the message that there is a danger using the Document Scanner program but I am unable to uninstall it.  I tried doing a purge of the Document Scanner from the Terminal but no luck.  It seems to be locked to my computer somehow.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt reinstall hplip hplip-gui` then rebooting?

Comment: how are you trying to delete `Document Scanner`? [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: I tried to uninstall the Document Scanner from the Ubuntu Store where it was shown as listed and installed and had the "Uninstall" shown.  That is where it didn't accomplish anything.  I finally did get it uninstalled somehow but it doesn't show in the store availability section but now it is an icon showing again on the computer???

Comment: I also in the terminal used the command